# FileWatcher - Delete and Shift + Delere not sending the same number of events

Tags: c#

I have a FileWatcher program written using C# - FileSystemWatcherClass

I have  nested folders (C:\F1\F2\F3\F4\Test.txt. When I copy the root folder F1 to the FileWatcher folder using Mouse, I used to get events for each folder separately, ie, **created** event for F1, F2,F3,F4 etc and Changed event for f1,f2,f3 etc.

But when I delete Folder F1, I am getting just a **deleted** event for F1. But if use **shift + delete**, I am getting **deleted** events for each folder separately.

Question:
Is it the windows functionality?
Can I capture each folder events **Deleted** separately for every folder , if I delete the folder F1 using the keyboard delete?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain but here's my guess:
When you "delete" directory F1 it is actually getting moved to the recycle directory, thus no actual delete is happening.  shift-delete tells windows to skip the recycle bin so you are seeing all the delete events.

something to try:  delete (to recycle bin) then empty the bin.  Since the recycle bin is not being watched it may or may not fire the delete events.

Comment: Thanks for  the quick response. I am trying to confirm  you point.

Comment: when I unCheck "Don't move files to the Recycle Bin. Remove files immediatley when deleted